# MAC applications to practice SQL

Tags: sql, database

I need a free application that I can use in practicing DDL and queries of SQL. I don't want applications that need to connect to some server. I tried [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) but it doesn't work always so I can't rely on it. I prefer one that support MySQL.
Note: If there is no such application for MAC OS X, please answer even with applications for other operating systems so I can use them on virtual machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install XAMPP. It comes bundled with a few services you can find useful. One being MySQL. You can use the interface on phpmyadmin and test your sql out there.

[XAMPP Download](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work. But can I use DDL statements (like CREATE TABLE...) to create the schema rather than using the menu-based way?

Comment: Yes you can. Phpmyadmin has SQL tabs you can use or you can even run the mysql service and connect through terminal

Comment: You mean that I can type the DDL commands in the SQL tab. But I didn't understand the other option "you can even run the mysql service and connect through terminal". Can you explain?

Comment: You can modify your database through a command line interface. Terminal in Mac OS you can have a look here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892904/how-do-i-access-mysql-from-mac-terminal-using-xampp