# Symfony 4 | Doctrine | An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've read every single post related to this issue but nothing seems to work for me.

I want to create a database with the following command:

$ php bin/console doctrine:database:create

The error is:

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:

  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  


In PDOConnection.php line 31:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  


In PDOConnection.php line 27:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  


doctrine:database:create [--shard SHARD] [--connection [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

What I have tried so far:

- I have updated the server version
- I changed 127.0.0.1 to localhost
- I created a new user in phpmyadmin

My **.env** file looks like this:

```
# IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version, either here or in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:123@127.0.0.1:3306/myproject?serverVersion=10.4.11
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

My **doctrine.yaml** file looks like this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        server_version: '10.4.11'

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: have you tried to login on the database with your credentials root:123 by using the comand line? eg mysql -u USERNAME -p

Comment: Mac and linux are very similar on the command line. first try mysql -v ... the version number should appear. Then mysql -uroot -p ... you will be asked for the password

Comment: usually mysql is linked in PATH... so you can access it from everywhere. no need for ./

Comment: The idea behind... if you can access the database by your credentials on the command line, the error needs more investigation. But I do expect a problem to login by your credentials and that is way you to be sure :-)

Comment: The version is: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.11-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: So apparently logging in by my credentials works

Comment: very good. After login with your credentials on the command line type SHOW DATABASES; ... you should see the standard databases. You can create a database with CREATE DATABASE YourDbName;  After this try to use the make command "php bin/console make:entity". Follow the instructions and create a table...  If still this still fails post the error

Comment: make sure you are in your project dir when using the make command

Comment: Okay, so I was able to create a database via the command line and create an entity within my project.

Comment: Probably Murphy's Law :-D
Probably it will work like a charm the next time. In the beginning, you somtimes miss something or your naming strategy is not good or you just had to clear the cache. There are many possibillities why it can fail but in most cases it will work.

Comment: Well, I guess this case isn't fully solved yet. So, I was able to create an entity but if I want to migrate it with "php bin/console make:migration" I am getting the same "connection refused" error as in the beginning with the "php bin/console doctrine:database:create" command

Comment: E.g. I want to migrate $title and $content for a simple article application

Comment: so you succeeded on the command line only? you created the entity but you did not follow the subsequent instructions eg make:migration and doctrine:migration:migrate?
If yes... you may have an error in your config. do you have next to your .env also an .env.local or/and an .env.dev?  These both will overwrite the settings.

Comment: I put actual code of a symfony5 project in the answer. Hope this helps. Another way is to debug is make use of the debug toolbar after creating a controller action with a repository request OR you first look for the error log of your local webserver. Since there are various possibillities on a MAC, you will have to find them by yourself.

Comment: So what I did was create a database with the xampp terminal, then I created an entity within my project and when I wanted to execute the command make:migration I got the same error again

Comment: I do not have a .env.local or .env.dev file next to my .env file

Comment: I have the same code that you posted down below in my respective files, but it doesn't work, I'm looking into the debug toolbar now

Comment: Okay so I manually created a table in phpmyadmin since I can't migrate my properties in src/Entity/Article.php. The table contains "title" and "content". The repository request is completely working. So I am able to display the title and body of my articles.

Comment: Something in your build must be wrong.If for any of the ff items, you say YES it is probably better to make a new project. Follow therefore, the instructions at https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html

- using VirtualBox
- workingDir is not in your HomeDir
- your Server is not on a local machine

Comment: btw, Maria DB is very powerful but for most projects, esp. for a beginner, it is probably better to use MySQL instead. Another hint is SymfonyCast. The actual course is suited best for you is "Charming Development in Symfony 5". It is not very expensive and very helpful. I remember my first setUp which was also full of problems :-) 
The hard way to learn a new framework takes a lot of time ... and nerves

Comment: Well I guess, starting on a new project makes more sense as you say even though none of the items you mentioned apply. Thanks for your time and advice! Appreciate it a lot!

Comment: So I started an entirely new Symfony 5 project and followed every step as it is mentioned in the Symfony Documentation, from setting up the project to using doctrine and I'm still getting the same error. Is there anything else I can do? Reset my Mac :-D?

Comment: It is not neccessary to reset your MAC. Try to uninstall XAMPP and reinstall just MySQL. You don't need the webserver for local development since you use the Symfony binaries. Follow the instructions while configuring MySQL. 
Open a terminal(!) (for details have a look on https://support.apple.com/de-de/guide/terminal/apd5265185d-f365-44cb-8b09-71a064a42125/mac ) and login as mentioned earlier. That is just for being sure. After this, follow the instrcutions of https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#installing-doctrine   if not done yet. This should work.

Comment: It's driving me nuts, I just can't fix the problem. So first, I successfully reinstalled XAMPP and MySQL as you said. Then I executed the **composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton MyProject** command in the htdocs directory of XAMPP. So I opened the project and executed **composer require symfony/orm-pack** and **composer require --dev symfony/maker-bundle** as mentioned here https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#installing-doctrine. Then I configured the .env file and executed **php bin/console doctrine:database:create**. Same error... :-(

Comment: Am I missing a step here or what am I doing? I did exactly these steps.

Comment: On the other hand, assuming I would use the Symfony binary as Symfonycasts is using it in their tutorial here https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony they still don't explain how to actually use doctrine in Symfony 5 or is it the same as in Symfony 4? Since XAMPP comes with MySQL, would I still communicate with the XAMPP MySQL Database using Symfony Binary? Sorry for asking such nooby questions, but as you can see I'm really new to the framework and I have barely any programming background.

Comment: Using the binary is just making life easier. So.. let us evaluate your problem: You have MySQL but you cannot bind it to doctrine! You testest the MySQL credentials by login on a terminal to your MySQL server. You can access the login without sudo. 
Have you tested to have just one(!) instance of MySQL on your local machine?
On a previously comment you talked about a XAMP terminal... is this a special tool or did you use the basic terminal of your system. This is important!

Comment: Yes, XAMPP comes with an apache server and MySQL. I am running my project on the apache server and want to bind doctrine to MySQL. I can access and login via the XAMPP terminal without sudo. I only have one instance of MySQL. I did not use the basic terminal, however, I did use the XAMPP terminal, that comes with the installation of XAMPP. The XAMPP Terminal says the following:

Comment: Warning: Permanently added '192.168.64.2' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Linux debian 4.9.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.189-3+deb9u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
root@debian:~#

Comment: The reason why I did not use the basic terminal was because I just didn't know how to access MySQL via the basic terminal. My path to MySQL is:

Comment: /Users/myname/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/bin/mysql

Comment: But **mysql -u root -p** doesn't work there. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892904/how-do-i-access-mysql-from-mac-terminal-using-xampp)

Comment: Assuming that I would use the Symfony binary and wouldn't have XAMPP. I would still need a MySQL installation, right? Where do I get it from and how do I set it up? The reason why I am sticking so much to XAMPP is, because I have done all my learning with it so far and really like the phpmyadmin surface

Comment: test on your terminal /Users/myname/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/bin/mysql -u root -p123. If this works, your installation is ok. I am not very familar with OSX but it seems your problem is to access your database server. It looks like your server is living on 192.168.64.2 not on localhost (127.0.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

This is what standard doctrine.yaml may look like (SF5.0!, Doctrine2.0)

//YOUR_NAMESPACE\config\packages\doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        server_version: '10.4'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'YOUR_NAMESPACE\Entity'
                alias: YOUR_NAMESPACE
```

and the .env.local

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:123@127.0.0.1:3306/myproject2
```

your composer.json should contain in the require segment

```
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.0",
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "2.1.*",
"doctrine/orm": "2.7.*",
```

and in your doctrine_migrations.yaml

//YOUR_NAMESPACE\config\packages\doctrine_migrations.yaml

```
doctrine_migrations:
    dir_name: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Migrations'
    # namespace is arbitrary but should be different from App\Migrations
    # as migrations classes should NOT be autoloaded
    namespace: DoctrineMigrations
```